# android - Format Double and put it in TextView without comma (if needed)

Tags: java, android, format, double

I get the "price" value from the server in `Double` and I need to put it in TextView in my application. The problem is: when price = 500 I get 500.0 because it's `Double`. I want it to look like 500.55 or 500.50 or just 500 - how do I format these numbers in the right way?

Comment: Split String respect to `.` and then remove`[1]` position

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `rexgex` to do the formatting

1.) Create a function to identify the following conditions

- If precision values contains only zeros then truncate them
- If there is any non-zero value after decimal then return original value

  ```
  public String formatValue(double d){
      String dStr = String.valueOf(d);
      String value = dStr.matches("\\d+\\.\\d*[1-9]\\d*") ? dStr : dStr.substring(0,dStr.indexOf("."));       
      return value;
  }
  ```

`\\d+\\.\\d*[1-9]\\d*` : match one or more digits then a `.`

- `\\d*[1-9]\\d*`  : match one non-zero value

Test cases

```
    yourTextView.setText(formatValue(500.00000000)); // 500
    yourTextView.setText(formatValue(500.0001));       // 500.0001
    yourTextView.setText(formatValue(500));          // 500
    yourTextView.setText(formatValue(500.1111));     // 500.1111
```

[Learn more about regular expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Answer (score 2):

Use [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)

```
double price = 500.0;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("0.###");
System.out.println(format.format(price));
```

**EDIT**

Ok, than try something different:

```
public static String formatPrice ( double price){
    if (price == (long) price)
        return String.format("%d", (long) price);
    else
        return String.format("%s", price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the String#format method.

Read about it here: https://www.dotnetperls.com/format-java
or in the JavaDoc

Answer (score -1):

You need to explicitly get the int value using method intValue() like this:

Double d = 5.25;
Integer i = d.intValue();

OR
double d = 5.25;
int i = (int) d;

Comment: @YagamiLight sure.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/01/how-to-convert-double-to-int-in-java.html
http://www.studytonight.com/java/type-casting-in-java